# Hyperlink to a bookmark inside the pdf from html

Tags: php, javascript, html, asp.net, pdf

Can we set **hyperlink** in html page to open a **pdf and hyperlink** to a bookmark inside the pdf.

**For example.**

> There is link "Click here" in the html page. If a use click this link,
>   it will open a pdf "test.pdf". This pdf got some bookmarks. So can we
>   set hyperlink to open and focus on the particular bookmark?

Thanks

Comment: You know, that's a very good question. Theoretically, one would think that by setting a simple `href` with an `anchor` would work, yet I'm under the impression that this may be a bit more complicated than that. Try the solution(s) below, see if that works for you. Have you Google'd it and have you tried anything?

Comment: I found a link to a page that is relevant to your question: http://www.planetpdf.com/enterprise/article.asp?ContentID=6426 so I guess it wasn't that complex after all, merely a plain `href` with an `anchor`, voilà!

Comment: HI @Fred...very nice link..it more useful for other also...once upon a time,i also struggled in this part.Thank you so much man...

Comment: @VIVEK-MDU You're very much welcome. I'm thinking to almost make it as an answer lol!

Answer (score 1):

You can make a link like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/info.pdf#page=5">Click here</a>
```

Or specifically for bookmarks, the pagemode has to be set:

```
<a href="http://example.org/doc.pdf#pagemode=bookmarks&page=2">Click here</a>
```

Please read more in [Adobe´s documentation.](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters_v9.pdf)

Comment: Good answer, yet you need to explain the "how" and "why" it works.

Comment: @Fred - It works because that's the format that Adobe uses as per their documentation in the link above.

Comment: Then may I suggest you write what you just wrote to me? lol It's just a suggestion, cheers

Comment: A minor remark: most of those open parameters only work with Adobe Reader and hardly any other PDF viewer.

Comment: @Fred - I already referrd to the documentation with an earnest plea to click on the link. I would even suggest the same for you, Fred. Maybe you don't need a link to a PDF, but maybe there would be something that you could gain from the experience as I did.

Comment: @PédeLeão Yes indeed, you're right. I too appreciate learning, and from others as well :) "SO" is a good resource/community for it.

Comment: @mkl **"Good thing is"**, I only gave a comment/suggestion and didn't make it as an actual "answer", at the risk of possibly getting downvoted. However, any added/relevant information to a problem is a way to further our knowledge and in helping someone, while hopefully **"finding a solution"**.